# Search a webpage and click on a button

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA on a webpage. I figured out how to log on and submit my username and password.

I need to click 3 buttons. They appear once the previous button has been clicked. I have my if statements, which do work if I go through the code piece by piece.

It looks like it loops through each statement several times. It goes through the if then part, then to exit for, end if, next and goes back to the if statement without accomplishing the task. It does this several times until eventually it works.

I have tried `.document.getElementsbyId` and all those related to that do not work.

Maybe there is a way to search the document and get it to click the button?

It seems its not working because its not true till eventually it is?

```
'Enters username and password & submits

With .document.forms("signinginn")
    .User.Value = "username"
    .Password.Value = "password"
    .document.forms(0).submit
End With

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)

With IE.document
    Set a = .getElementsbyTagName("input") 

    For Each a In .getElementsbyTagName("input")

        If a.getAttribute("value") = "Start" Then
            a.Click
            Exit For
        End If

    Next a
```

This code works if I play it part by part, but it goes through several times.

Am I able to get it right the first time? The expected output of this code is to immediately click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a timed loop for element to be present, proper page load waits and also using querySelector to remove your current loop and simply target the attribute value of input element

```
Option Explicit

'VBE > Tools > References: Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub ClickElement()
    Dim ie As Object, elems As Object, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "url"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document.forms("signinginn")
            .User.Value = "username"
            .Password.Value = "password"
            .document.forms(0).submit
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set elems = .document.querySelectorAll("input[value=Start]")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While elems Is Nothing
        If Not elems Is Nothing Then
            elems.item(0).Click
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'Other code
        Stop   '<=Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It's saying error 438 (object doesn't support this property or method) on the While .Busy line right before t= Timer

Comment: Also, I commented out that line to see the issue, but I sitll have this same issue where it is looping through over and over

Comment: Ok my old code works if i do it piece by piece, however yours works if I just press continue

Comment: It is method of internet explorer so should not complain. Did you just add in your url?

Comment: Yes, the stop command works. However, if I individually loop through the program, it loops and loops and loops till it works. If I just press play- the program works

Comment: That is how it is supposed to run. It means it is working properly. It loops until the required element is present. Removed the need for pressing f8.